# Js скрипт на игровые кости

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать js и решил сделать игру в кости. Вопрос такой, как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кость, 1 секунду быстро менялись все случайные варианты исхода кости и только потом уже выдавал случайный результат

Comment: Посмотрите setInterval, getElementBy*, querySelector*

Comment: Можно не вычислять `все случайные варианты исхода`, а просто проиграть заранее записанную анимацию.